# I was trying to merge two lists and my merge function is not running properly. The program just terminates when I call merge function

Tags: c++, merge, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I tried putting dummy statements to find out the problem. It seems the problem occurs at the end of the `merge()` function at
`p->next=list2;` but I do not know what the problem is.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int value, count, value2, count2,choice;

struct node
{
    int data;
    node * next;
};

node *list = nullptr;
node *list2 = nullptr;
node * p;
node * q;
node * r;

void insertFront()
{
    cout << "ENTER A VALUE=";
    cin >> value;

    if (list == nullptr)
    {
        p = new node();
        p->data = value;
        p->next = nullptr;
        list = p;
    }
    else
    {
        p = new node();
        p->data = value;
        p->next = list;
        list = p;
    }
}

void insertFront2()
{
    cout << "ENTER A VALUE=";
    cin >> value;

    if (list2 == nullptr)
    {
        r = new node();
        r->data = value;
        r->next = nullptr;
        list2 = r;
    }
    else
    {
        r = new node();
        r->data = value;
        r->next = list2;
        list2 = r;
    }
}

void delFront()
{
    if (list == nullptr)
    {
        cout << "LIST IS ALREADY EMPTY";
    }
    else
    {
        p = list;
        list = p->next;
        delete(p);
    }
}

void display(int choice)
{
    int select=choice;

    if (select == 1)
    {
        p = list;
    }
    if (select == 2)
    {
        p = list2;
    }
    while (p != nullptr)
    {
        cout << p->data << " ";
        p = p->next;
    }

    cout << endl;
}

void mergeLists(node *list,node *list2)
{
    if (list==nullptr and list2==nullptr){
        cout<<"Both lists are empty";
    }

    else if(list==nullptr && list2!=nullptr){
        display(2);
    }

    else if(list2==nullptr && list!=nullptr){
        display(1);
    }
    if(list!=nullptr && list2!=nullptr){
        p=list;
        while(p!=nullptr){
            p=p->next;
        }

        p->next=list2;

        display(1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int choice;
    cout << "1) Insert at front " << endl;
    cout << "2) Delete at front" << endl;
    cout << "7) Merge two lists" << endl;
    cout << "9) Display" << endl << endl;
    while (choice != 99)
    {
        cout << "Your choice:";
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                {
                    int sel;
                    cout << "Enter the list to which you want to enter:\n 1 or 2\nYour choice:";
                    cin >> sel;
                    if (sel == 1)
                    {
                        insertFront();
                    }
                    else if (sel == 2)
                    {
                        insertFront2();
                    }

                    break;
                }

            case 2:
                {
                    delFront();
                    break;
                }

            case 7:
                {
                    mergeLists(list,list2);

                    break;
                }

            case 9:
                {
                    int sel;
                    cout<<"Select a list to display: 1/2"<<endl;
                    cin>>sel;
                    display(sel);
                    break;
                }

            case 99:
                {
                    cout << "PROGRAM TERMINATED :)";
                    break;
                }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: i dont know how to use a debugger

Comment: Time to learn.  You'll be glad you did

Comment: [What is a debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Debuggers differe a bit from toolchain to toolchain, but the way you use it is always the same. Here's [how to use the debugger in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2022). Other GUI IDE debuggers ill be extremely similar, they just move the buttons around a bit and use different hotkeys.

Comment: General gist is you put a breakpoint before the bug you want to kill (if you don't know where that is, start at the beginning of `main`) and start stepping line-by-line. Pay attention to what the program does and when you see something unexpected, like the program storing the wrong value or taking the wrong path, stop and investigate closer. Restart the program and get a better look at what lead up to the unexpected behaviour, because the bug is almost certainly somewhere nearby.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `merge()`, you are looping through `list` until `p` becomes `nullptr`, thus `p` is `nullptr` when you try to access `p->next` after the loop.

You need to fix your loop to stop when it reaches the last node, not when it goes past the last node, eg:

```
void mergeLists(node *list, node *list2)
{
    if (!list && !list2){
        cout << "Both lists are empty";
    }

    else if (!list && list2){
        display(2);
    }

    else if (!list2 && list){
        display(1);
    }

    else {
        p = list;
        while (p->next){
            p = p->next;
        }

        p->next = list2;

        display(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Answering these kinds of questions just encourages people to post more of them...

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso this is a Q&A site, we are here to answer questions, including beginner questions like this. Not everyone has access to *good-quality* programming education.

Answer (score 0):

For starters if you want to append the second list `list2` to the first list `list` then after the calling the function `merge` the  list `list2` should be empty.

Within the function merge after this while loop

```
    while(p!=nullptr){
        p=p->next;
    }
```

the pointer `p` is a null pointer. So using the null pointer to access memory in this statement

```
    p->next=list2;
```

results in undefined behavior.

And this if statement

```
if(list!=nullptr && list2!=nullptr){
```

is redundant.

Using your approach the function can be defined the following way

```
void mergeLists(node *list,node *list2)
{
    if ( list == nullptr and list2 == nullptr )
    {
        cout<<"Both lists are empty";
    }
    else if ( list == nullptr && list2 != nullptr )
    {
        
        list = list2;
        list2 = nullptr; 
        display(1);
    }
    else if ( list2 == nullptr && list != nullptr )
    {
        display(1);
    }
    else
    {
        p = list;

        while ( p->next != nullptr )
        {
            p = p->next;
        }

        p->next = list2;
        list2 = nullptr;

        display(1);
    }
}
```

Pay attention to that it is a bad idea to make functions depend on global variables. For example if you will want to use one more list you will need to rewrite your functions.

Also you have too much redundant code as for example in the functions `insertFront` and `insertFront2`. They can be defined much simpler. For example

```
void insertFront()
{
    cout << "ENTER A VALUE = ";
    cin >> value;

    list = new node { value, list };
}
```

and

```
void insertFront2()
{
    cout << "ENTER A VALUE = ";
    cin >> value;

    list2 = new node { value, list2 };
}
```

Comment: In that case, when you are able, please accept Vlad's answer.  Thx.